# How to ensure implicit variable is passed from trait to method?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a trait written as follows:

```
trait NewTrait { 
  def NewTrait(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result):  Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action { request =>
      implicit val newTrait = new model.helper.newTrait
      f(request) 
    }
  }
}
```

And a controller that uses that trait, and tries to pass the implicit val newTrait to a view:

```
object Test extends Controller with NewTrait {

  def foo(num: Int) = NewTrait { request =>
    val view = (views.html.example.partials.viewWrap)       
    Ok(views.html.example.examplePage(views.html.shelfPages.partials.sidebar())
}
```

In foo, newTrait won't be in scope, but what would the best practice be for bringing it into scope? It has to be unique to each request received. It works if I re-declare the implicit val from within foo, but I'd have to repeat that declaration each time within the controller and the code would look a lot cleaner if I could hide that away in the trait. Is there any way to have the implict value in the trait be passed on to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make the said val a field variable:

```
trait NewTrait { 
  implicit val newTrait = new model.helper.newTrait
  ...
}
```

Now it will be in method `foo` scope.

Comment: It brings it into scope of the method, but it will no longer be unique to the request sent. For example, on page refresh of the view, the data persists from that variable, but that is not desired - it should reset.

Comment: Then you should use a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Although I found the names to be a bit confusing (it's probably example code) this is how you could do it:

```
trait NewTrait {
  def NewTrait(f: Request[AnyContent] => model.helper.newTrait => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action { request =>
      val newTrait = new model.helper.newTrait
      f(request)(newTrait)
    }
  }
}
```

And in the code that uses it:

```
object Test extends Controller with NewTrait {
  def foo(num: Int) = NewTrait { request => implicit newTrait =>
    Ok
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```scala
trait NewTrait {
    def gotRequest(req:Request) = {
        implicit val newTrait = new model.helper.newTrait
        // don't have to pass the newTrait parameter here 
        // explicitly, it is used implicitly
        Whatever.f(request)
    }
}
```

and:

```
object Whatever {
    def f(req:Request)(implicit val newTrait:NewTrait) = {
        //newTrait is in scope here.

        //...the rest of your code
    }
}
```